# How to Create TableRecord Object?

Tags: java, jooq

i was trying to create method **(Which is a common method so that i can pass any Table class object to it )**  like below which will take `List` of `TableRecord` as a argument and get table name and column names as well so i am doing below code .

```
public void getColumns(List<TableRecord> records){
    for(TableRecord record : records){
        Table table = record.getTable();

        Field[] fields = table.fields();
        for(Field field : fields){
            field.getName();
            record.getValue(field);

        }
    }
}
```

but my question here how to create a object of `TableRecord` class? so that i can call the above method and pass `List` of `TableRecord` object.

I was trying a generic method which will get  [TableRecord](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org%24maven2@org.jooq%24jooq@3.0.1@org%24jooq%24TableRecord.java)  object and return the database table name and all the column's that table have . I have to use `TableRecord` or any other object for this and how to create that object?

I can not do something like this

```
TableRecord record = new  TableRecord()
```

because it already a interface then how to create object? Or i have to pass another class to method?

**EDIT :-**

If you will see my code you can check method taking `List` of `TableRecord` as a argument so that this `List`  can take any DB table JOOQ class like `LoginRecord.java`,`EmpRecord.java` etc. So method is not generic and its broad, developer can pass any type of Jooq created table class object by this. Now i have '`List<TableRecord>`' object now i have to get columnName or fieldName and their value i mean data those fields contain, so that i can set data to another bean class which will interact with UI.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18914017/521799

Comment: Are you using jOOQ's code generator at all?

Comment: Yes i am newbie in Jooq and table generated by Jooq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At firt you need to know that `TableRecord` is an interface so it is obvious you cannot crate it on your code. What you need to do is find class which implements this interface and fits your requirements. Since jooq hierarchy is very complicated I try to show you how to find best option.

```
public interface TableRecord<R extends TableRecord<R>> extends Record
```

then this interface is in:

```
public interface UpdatableRecord<R extends UpdatableRecord<R>> extends TableRecord<R>
```

And jooq have it's implementations:

```
public class TableRecordImpl<R extends TableRecord<R>> extends AbstractRecord implements TableRecord<R>
public class AddressRecord extends org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl<AddressRecord> implements org.jooq.Record8<Integer, String, String, String, Float, Float, Integer, String>
public class UpdatableRecordImpl<R extends UpdatableRecord<R>> extends TableRecordImpl<R> implements UpdatableRecord<R>
```

**Time for practise**

This is just a base scaffolding of Jooq but one thing is important. As far as you are using jooq you more likely have generated tables, and tables record for each database table in your code.
This can look like:

```
public class AddressRecord extends org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl<AddressRecord> implements org.jooq.Record8<Integer, String, String, String, Float, Float, Integer, String>
```

So your all records extends `org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl<AddressRecord>` which in fact `implements TableRecord<R>`

**Method parameter**

As far as you use interface as parameter you can use polimorphic calls to every object which implements `TableRecord<R>`. In this case you can put here all of your records.

```
List<TableRecord> records = new List<TableRecord>();
records.add(new AddressRecord());
records.add(new CityRecord());
records.add(new UserRecord());
```

---

**EDIT**

**Is this code generic?**

If you want this code work for any kind of `TableRecord` this code is suitable for you. But this code is not strictly `generic` because you don't use generic types. Nevertheless I would keep this code in that manner.

Comment: Thanks for your brief explanation let me try your solution right now i can not do +1 due to less reputation sorry for that. One more question here i have to get value of column and name diffrently

Comment: The approach which i am doing to make method more generic is looks ok or i am doing something wrong please advise me on that also?

Comment: @Hariom - I cannot understand your first question please explain it more precisly.

Comment: We got Table Object from this 'Table table = record.getTable();
' now we can get columnName or fieldName and i want value of that field as well so that i can set these value to another class

Comment: if we are doing 'List<TableRecord> records ' from my understanding its broadly used by any table sorry to use generic word here.

Answer (score 2):

From your comments I take that you are using jOOQ's code generator to generate tables. Hence, you do not need to try to instanciate `TableRecord`, but use the generated references instead. In order to create new records, just use:

```
MyTableRecord record = DSL.using(configuration).newRecord(MY_TABLE);
```

This is [`DSLContext.newRecord(Table)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#newRecord%28org.jooq.Table%29) as explained in the chapters about [using jOOQ for CRUD](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.1/manual/sql-execution/crud-with-updatablerecords/)

Comment: May be i am not able to understand clearly how to create my method generic so that i can pass any List table object to it and get columnName and data by above code?

Comment: What's wrong with your method? Do you want a list of records or a list of tables?

Comment: When i will pass table list to my method i will iterate with it get tableName,columnname and value or data of that column and i have to set these value to another data bean class with get/set method, which is my own class that why i am writing this method so that i can pass any JOOQ created Table class to it and my method will create list of object MyClass type.

Comment: I'm afraid but that explanation did not really contribute to my understanding of your problem...

Comment: If you will see my code you can check i taken List of 'TableRecord' as a argument so that this 'List' can take any DB table JOOQ class like Login.java,Record.java etc. So method is generic by this. Now i have 'List<TableRecord>' object now i have to get columnName or fieldName  so that i can set them to another bean class which will interact with UI.

Comment: Can you please update your question in a way that it is *very clear* what your real (remaining?) problem is? Also, please do not ask 2-3 questions in one Stack Overflow question. This is very confusing for readers.

Comment: Edited question again